# Dark conical shape appeared in solid view clipping display of objects

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I was setting up a render border, but instead must have pressed something wrong (I'm not sure what) and this is what I ended up with:

[image: dark shape in solid view]

Basically, there is a darker, conical or pyramid shape in the solid view and it restricts (clips) what parts of items are visible.

I want to disable it, but because I don't know how it is called or what I did to enable it in the first place, I can't find the option.

What is this feature called and how to disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By accident you set View Clipping Border with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> shortcut, to disable it hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> again.