# Blender: Strange clipping planes when rotating the view

Tags: objects, 3d-view

I am experiencing strange clipping behavior that is shown in the gif below.  Why are my grid and cube being clipped when I rotate my view about the Y Axis?  Everything seems normal when my view is aligned with the +/- Z Axis.

For what it's worth, I've changed my Units to Metric, and my unit scale is .001.  For a higher quality gif, I have one at this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ0hw.jpg).

[image]

Comment: adjust the clip distance for the viewport. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8553/why-does-part-of-my-model-disappear-when-i-zoom-in-on-it-in-the-3d-viewport/8554#8554

Comment: See also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52572/dark-conical-shape-appeared-in-solid-view-clipping-display-of-objects